# RGB Color, wrong color

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am currently working on an iOS Application in Swift 3 and wanted to change the color of my `NavigationBar` 
with the following code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 53.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 90.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

This code works quite fine but there's one problem. The color I entered in RGB format is displayed wrong.

Should be like this color: [image]

But looks like this (left: is current Color () right: as already said should look like):

[image]

Comment: Did you set the translucent property to NO?

Comment: Set navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Comment: I think I know what you mean. I had an similar issue years ago. I realised that there are differente RGB types generic RGB, adobe RGB, sRGB. I am not sure if it's that but it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false.

You can also achieve this by unchecking Translucent from storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change navigation bar to Opaque instead of Translucent.

**Swift**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
```

Please find in image.

[image]

> And if you are setting navigations background color then change
>   navigation background color instead of tint color.